# Como pegar o último id inserido no asp.net?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Estou fazendo um site no ASP.NET, e preciso cadastrar um usuário/cliente. A questão é: assim que eu inserir os valores na tabela `users`, eu preciso pegar o `id` dessa tabela e usar na tabela `end_user` (tabela do endereço do user) para cadastrar o resto das informações do usuário. Como posso fazer isso? Tentei usar o `last_insert_id()`, mas dá erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT last_insert_id() = NULL' at line 1

Porque dá `null`?

As tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome_us TEXT NOT NULL,
snome_us TEXT NOT NULL,
rg_us TEXT NOT NULL,
cpf_us TEXT NOT NULL,
email_us TEXT NOT NULL,
fone_us TEXT DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE end_user
(
id_user INT NOT NULL,
cep_us TEXT NOT NULL,
num_us TEXT NOT NULL,
comp_us TEXT,

FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user),

PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver utilizando [MysqlClient](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) para **C#** ou **VB.Net** ele já está implementado:

### Exemplo

```
var conexao = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand co = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("insert into ...", conexao);
co.ExecuteNonQuery();
long t = co.LastInsertedId; // recuperando aqui depois de executar o SQL de Insert !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser obter o último `id` inserido diretamente no banco de dados, você pode fazer:

```
INSERT INTO users (nome_us,...) VALUES ('Nome',...);
SET @last_id_in_users = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO end_user (id_user,...) VALUES (@last_id_in_users,...);
```

[Exemplo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8796e/1)